# Live Page View Counter in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently looking for a way in Rails/Javascript to show a live count of all users visiting a specific controller action. Think of it like a similar functionality to Twitch.tv channel viewers. I've seen some older instances of ways to accomplish this, but I'm new to rails and back end code in general, so I'm not exactly sure the best way to even think about this problem. Maybe there's a gem out there that would help me as well. If so, I'm definitely open to it.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

I strong suggest that you take a look at ActionCable feature. Its native, so you don`t need any extra gems and, with a little bit of code, you can get real time feautures up and running.

[Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html)
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html